# Help evaluating this seemingly simple integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ = $\int$$\frac{1}{2e^z+1}$, this is a path integral along $|Z| = 4$

and i know from my textbook that:

[image]

My attempt:

singularity is at:

$2e^z = -1$
therefore at $z = ln|0.5|+2ik\pi$

therefore i need to find the residue at $ln|0.5|$ since it is the only residue that lies inside $C$

since ln|0.5| is a first order  pole i wont need to differentiate and just end up with:

$Res(f(z), ln|0.5|)$ = $\lim_{z\to ln|0.5|}$$\frac{z - ln|0.5|}{e^z+1}$=$0.5$ NB(not sure if i can use L'Hôpital's rule here, though seems like the only way forward)

and therefore the answer to the integral is:
$\int$$\frac{1}{e^z+1}$ = $2i\pi$$0.5$ = $i\pi$

however my textbook says the answer is $-4i$$\pi$ please help me out with this..

Thanks!

Comment: Poles are at $\log{(1/2)} + i (2 k+1) \pi$.

Comment: i honestly dont see how knowing that can help me get the right answer, a little hint please?

Comment: Well, you seemed to know what to do when you had the wrong pole.

Comment: @RonGordon sorry i may not have explained that too well, what i was trying to say is that given that i use log(1/2)+i(2k+1)π as my pole, i get the following:$Res(f(z), -ln|2| + i $$\pi$)$ = $$\lim_{z\to -ln|2|+ i \pi}$$\frac{z + ln|2| - i \pi}{e^z+1}$ and i still dont see how this can evaluate to -4i$\pi$ therefore i was hoping you could give me a hint on how i can get that answer.. thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Hint: $$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{z-z_o}{f(z)-f(z_0)} = \frac1{f'(z_0)} $$

Comment: $Res(f(z), -ln|2| + i $$\pi$)$ = $$\lim_{z\to -ln|2|+ i \pi}$$\frac{z + ln|2| - i \pi}{e^z+1}$ = $0/0$ and therefore can use L'Hôpital's rule: i.e differentiating the top and bottom to get:

$\lim_{z\to -ln|2|+ i \pi}$$\frac{1}{2e^z}$ = $\frac{1}{2e^{-ln|2|+ i \pi}}$ = $\frac{1}{1e^{i\pi}}$ = -1

therefore the integral evaluates to 2$i\pi$*-1 = -2$\pi$i and my textbook says the right answer is a $-4i\pi$ is there something i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Any other poles inside $|z| < 4$?

Comment: i don't think so: i think the only pole from:  log(1/2)+i(2k+1)π thats inside C is @ k = 0 i.e log(1/2)+iπ < 4 @ k = 1 it goes out of the region i think; or is the something i'm missing?

Comment: $k=-1$? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I was not aware that k could be negative i thought it went from 0,1,2..n would you please explain to me what its bounds are and also i know this may be a stupid question but is z = log(1/2)+i(2k+1)π. every time you take logs or are there conditions.. thanks.

Comment: At this point, I must move on.  If this is for a class, get a tutor.  Thanks.